# EXCEPTION - There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first. (System.Data)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a backpack file and I am trying to import it but when I do that in SQL Server I get exception as

> "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command
>   which must be closed first. (System.Data)"

. Please guide me how to get rid of this exception.

I read solution online and it tells about changing some settings in connection string, but I am not sure how to do that at SQL Server Layer.

Steps to reproduce

1. Right click on `Databases`
2. Click on `Import Data-tier application`
3. Select the backfile
4. Exception occurs when clicked  "Next"

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of SSMS?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - Added it as the screenshot

Comment: Your software is out of date.  18.3.1 was released on 10/2/19.  The version you're running, 18.0.18075.0 is preview and has been superseded.  Please update your software and try the action again.

Comment: You guys are real rock star, Downloaded the latest version and it fixed the issue.